# Visual Studio 2010 Oracle CLR Project - Can not deploy project (ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle, oracle11g, clr

I've set up a local Oracle database on my system and can connect via both SqlDeveloper and Sql*Plus (sqlplus system/mypassword@ORACLE), but when I try to setup the ODP.Net connectionstring in the deployment options of a Visual Studio 2010 CLR Project then I get a ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Actions I do:
Visual Studio 2010
File

- New Project
- Database
- Oracle
- Visual C# Oracle Project

Build

- Deploy
- The Oracle Deployment Wizard is started where I create a New Connection with the following specifics:
- Data Source: Oracle Database (ODP.NET)
- Data Source Name: ORACLE
- User Name: SYSTEM
- Pass: mypassword
- Test Connection
- ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the conect identifier specified

The contents of my tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:     c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORACLE)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

The contents of my listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:     c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS =     "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost.domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = c:\app\oracle
```

The contents of sqlnet.ora:

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File:     c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question: solved this issue by replacing myhost.domain.com by localhost in my listener.ora